# In python, I received this error TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x

My code so far:

```
def book_point():
      displayoints = 0
      books = 0
      setmessage()
      books = bookinput()
      displayoints = display(bookinput)

    def setmessage():
      print ("Hello, please enter the number of books that you has purchased this month and we will displays the points awarded you have")

    def bookinput():
      books = 0
      books = int(input("Enter number: "))
      return books

    def display(bookinput):
      if bookinput == 0:
       print ("You have 0 point")
      elif bookinput == 1:
       print ("You have 5 points awarded")
      elif bookinput == 2:
       print ("You have 15 points awarded")
      elif bookinput == 3:
       print ("You have 30 points awarded")
      elif bookinput >= 4:
        print ("You have 60 points awarded")
      else:
       print ("Invalid number")
    book_point()
```

and when executed, it say Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 29, in 
  File "python", line 6, in book_point
  File "python", line 25, in display
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'

Comment: Looks like bookinput should be books. bookinput is a function, so how do you compare bookinput >= 4?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I got the answer

```
def book_point():
  displayoints = 0
  books = 0
  setmessage()
  books = bookinput()
  displayoints = display(books)

def setmessage():
  print ("Hello, please enter the number of books that you has purchased this month and we will displays the points awarded you have")

def bookinput():
  books = 0
  books = int(input("Enter number: "))
  return books

def display(books):
  if books == 0:
    print ("You have 0 point")
  elif books == 1:
    print ("You have 5 points awarded")
  elif books == 2:
    print ("You have 15 points awarded")
  elif books == 3:
    print ("You have 30 points awarded")
  elif books >= 4:
    print ("You have 60 points awarded")
  else:
    print ("Invalid number")
book_point()
```